# VC++ Compiler Can't Catch HANDLE and PHANDLE Type Mismatch

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, void-pointers, type-mismatch

I spent a whole day looking for a bug caused by wrongly passing Windows PHANDLE type to a function expecting HANDLE!!!  I was expecting the VC++ 2010 compiler to catch such a simple and obvious type mismatch error.  However, it didn't.  It just didn't.

On a closer look, HANDLE is defined as void pointer in winnt.h and so PHANDLE is just void pointer pointer.  Since anything can be passed to void * or void ** so PHANDLE and HANDLE mismatch can't be warned by the compiler.

Is there anyway to avoid such a problem.  I don't know how many other Windows types are typedef'ed as void *.  Are there any strategies to avoid such errors?

For example, the following compiled without any error in VC++ 2010, although the function is called by wrong pointer types. And, it is not obvious the pitfall is there unless one knows HANDLE (or any other Windows types) is a void pointer:

```
void f1 (HANDLE h) {
  printf("%x",h);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  PHANDLE ph=NULL;
  int c=0;

  f1(ph);
  f1(&c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show a piece of code?

Comment: Source code added, see my edit.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio Ultimate, it comes with a code analyser. Not perfect, but it should catch most of these types of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to think of `HANDLE` is as the base type for all handles, such as `HWND`,`HDC` etc. Because C doesn't support the concept of a base type they had to make it a `void*`.

In most cases your app should be compiled with the `STRICT` flag set. This will ensure that all specific handles are actually based off of structures and so you won't have any issues. However, if you do write a method that works with a general `HANDLE` then you're going to have to be careful!

Comment: Definitely, `STRICT` should ALWAYS be used.